# Button should change paragraph <p> text when clicked based off JavaScript code but it's not changing text

Tags: javascript, html

So I've just began learning JavaScript and I wanted to change the text in my paragraph when the button is clicked but it's not working for some reason

```
<body> 
    <p id="paragraph">Change Text on click</p>     
    <button onclick="dosomething">
        You already know
    </button>
</body>
```

this is the HTML code and below is the JS

```
function dosomething(){
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = 'Button was clicked!';
}
```

this is all that's in the JS file so unless  I'm missing something this is it. I did correctly script the js file in the html head too

Comment: `onclick="dosomething()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function like `dosomething()` with the parenthesis:

```js
function dosomething(){
document.getElementById('yeezy').innerHTML = 'Tottenham';
}
```

```html
<p id="yeezy">What do we think of stuff</p>     
    <button onclick="dosomething()">
        You already know
    </button>
```